# Eclipse e4 - Add a Closing Part handler

Tags: java, eclipse, handler, rcp, e4

I'd like to implement an handler which is triggered every time I close a part of my Application Model.

How can I do?

For instance, every time I close such part I want to print a message thru the System Console.
Moreover is there any object (that could be injected) that provides the state of an MPart? (if it's open or close)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `addPartListener` method of `EPartService` to add a listener for changes to the state of parts:

```
@Inject
EPartService partService;

...

partService.addPartListener(IPartListener instance);
```

Be sure to import the correct `IPartListener` - `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.IPartListener`

Comment: Ok Greg, but I haven't got where I should bind this snippet. Should I create a new class? Or include it in the Part's class? Thanks

Comment: If you want to see all part changes put it in the [LifeCycle](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) class

Comment: Hey greg that's a cool type of class, but what does it change from a Processor Class? And where should I put the .removelistener entry? Always in LifeCycle? Since if I do not remove it I'll get an "exponential" number of calls to the listener class.

Comment: There is only one instance of the LifeCycle class created at startup